# CSS: Two column layout when only one column content has a wrapper element

Tags: html, css

Given the following structure:

```html
<form>
  <label for="id_foo">Foo:</label>
  <input type="text" name="foo" required="" id="id_foo">
  <label for="id_bar">Bar:</label>
  <input type="text" name="bar" required="" id="id_bar">
  <label for="id_baz">Baz:</label>
  <input type="text" name="baz" required="" id="id_baz">
  <label>Select:</label>
  <div id="id_select">
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

without modifying the html and assuming the number of check boxes is somewhat dynamic.

Can this be rendered sensibly in two columns:

- input fields fill one column after another
- with labels above each input within one row
- height of items on one column independent of those in the other column.

[image: target visualization]

I understand this is [trivial if I had a container for the tags of each column](https://jsfiddle.net/hwpvo7qn/1/), but I want to understand if/how it is possible to achieve without.

With grid layout, [I come close](https://jsfiddle.net/xh3u659s/), but I the number of checkboxes will influence the height of the input fields / labels on the left.

With `columns` / `column-count` I can't seem to find a way to control the break.

Note: The reason I don't want to modify the html is mostly because the framework I'm using (Django) does make it rather intrusive to mess with form rendering. Moreover, this specific layout is only for certain screen sizes. I dislike tuning the html with different responsive layouting in mind. I am willing to accept some additional complexity in the CSS in this case, and want to figure out if this is feasible.

Comment: a sketch of what you are trying to achieve would be useful – "labels above inputs" sounds like you want two rows, one with labels and one with inputs, but your jsfiddle shows columns oriented differently. not clear what is the outcome you are looking for.

Comment: @MishaReyzlin sure, I added a screenshot which is basically from the version with extra containers. That is what I want it to look like. I also tried to improve the description, apologies if the wording did / does not precisely convey what I am aiming for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `grid` display could help you.
defaut will draw a single column, unless you specify an element to stand in another column.

If you use ID , you may work something out wherever IDs are found or not.

Example with your form , with and without IDS , both are a `form{display:grid;}`

```css
   /* defaut layout as a grid of one column , gap can be used */
form {
display:grid;
gap:0.5em;
padding:0.5em;
border:solid;
margin:1em;
}
/* element dispatched inside grid-column:2 , will make form draw 2 columns */
#id_select {
grid-column:2;
grid-row:2 / 6;
display:grid;
}
#label_select{grid-row:1;}
#id_select ~input[type="submit"] {
grid-row:6;
}
#label_select,
#id_select ~input[type="submit"] {
grid-column:2;
}
```

```html
<h1>I'll be 2 columns !</h1>
<form>
  <label for="id_foo">Foo:</label>
  <input type="text" name="foo" required="" id="id_foo">
  <label for="id_bar">Bar:</label>
  <input type="text" name="bar" required="" id="id_bar">
  <label for="id_baz">Baz:</label>
  <input type="text" name="baz" required="" id="id_baz">
  <label id="label_select">Select:</label>
  <div id="id_select">
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<h2>I'll be a single column</h2>
<form>
  <label for="id_foo">Foo:</label>
  <input type="text" name="foo" required="" id="id_foo">
  <label for="id_bar">Bar:</label>
  <input type="text" name="bar" required="" id="id_bar">
  <label for="id_baz">Baz:</label>
  <input type="text" name="baz" required="" id="id_baz">
  <label>Select:</label>
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Another option can be to use behaviors of the table layout and put label and inputs inside the box.

Below example:

```css
/* defaut layout as a table of one column , border-spacing can be used */
form {
display:table;
position:relative;
width:90%;
border:solid;
margin:1em;
border-spacing:.5em;
}
form>label,form>input {display:block;width:95%}
#id_select { 
display:table-cell;
padding-bottom:2em;
width:50%;
padding-inline-start:0.5em;
border-inline-start:double;
}

#id_select ~ input[type="submit"] {
position:absolute;
bottom:1em;
left:50%;
right:0;
}
input[type="submit"] {
margin:auto;
width:auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>I'll be 2 columns !</h1>
<form>
  <label for="id_foo">Foo:</label>
  <input type="text" name="foo" required="" id="id_foo">
  <label for="id_bar">Bar:</label>
  <input type="text" name="bar" required="" id="id_bar">
  <label for="id_baz">Baz:</label>
  <input type="text" name="baz" required="" id="id_baz">
  <div id="id_select">
    <label id="label_select">Select:</label>
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<h2>I'll be a single column</h2>
<form>
  <label for="id_foo">Foo:</label>
  <input type="text" name="foo" required="" id="id_foo">
  <label for="id_bar">Bar:</label>
  <input type="text" name="bar" required="" id="id_bar">
  <label for="id_baz">Baz:</label>
  <input type="text" name="baz" required="" id="id_baz">
  <label>Select:</label>
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: With that approach, I have the issue that if there are too many checkboxes, the elements on the left begin to stretch unevenly. Do you have a suggestion on how to prevent that?

Comment: @Zulan, hello do you have a snippet example i can look at ?  (min-width could partially do)

Comment: My issue is with the height distribution, e.g. see this example https://jsfiddle.net/wntqa6bk/

Comment: @Zulan hello, you can increase the numbers of rows to span, to avoir stretching the one in the first column.

Comment: @zulan or use an older method about the table layout (added a snippet to the answer)

Answer (score 0):

What I’d do is put the `#id_select` in a absolutely positioned block on the right top, which would prevent it from affecting the height of the main content with labels+inputs.

```css
form {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 100px;
  /* make space for the #id_select block */
}

label,
input {
  display: block;
  /* make them fill in width to go one after another vertically */
}

#id_select {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="id_foo">Foo:</label>
  <input type="text" name="foo" required="" id="id_foo">
  <label for="id_bar">Bar:</label>
  <input type="text" name="bar" required="" id="id_bar">
  <label for="id_baz">Baz:</label>
  <input type="text" name="baz" required="" id="id_baz">
  <label>Select:</label>
  <div id="id_select">
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox"><label>Test</label></div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach. But getting that to properly distribute the width by two is probably a lot of calculation. But I see how this might work out when the two column layout is applied to a fixed total width.